# Div click initiate containing button click with animation

Tags: css

I have div with a button inside it. I want when a user clicks on the div (outside the button's rect) to initiate the button click with its animation. Is there any simple css solution, without javascript?

Comment: The short answer is "No".  You want to attach the click event to div, and that requires JavaScript.

Comment: it's possible, but do it with JS

Comment: It is possible, but you should probably explain what you want to do. Here's a basic [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/e8dna8wq/) using the `:target` pseudoclass. This does not trigger the button's click event though.